# Using a control in WiX to save an ID to config file

Tags: c#, wpf, wix

I have a Wix installer already set up. I wish to add an input field to accept an ID (eg. ABC123) and then save that ID to the App.config file as a key. How would I go about doing this for my application? (I have several machines that need content pushed out to them based on this ID)

Here is a sample of how I started to go about this. I'm not proficient enough in WiX as of now.

```
<Component Id="Settings">
  <util:XmlFile 
        Id="XmlSettingsUpdate"
        Action="setValue"
        File="[INSTALLDIR]/$(var.ProductName.exe.config)"
        SelectionLanguage="XPath"
        Permanent="yes"
        ElementPath="//appSettings/add"
        Name="StationId" Value="[addStationId]" />
</Component>
```

And I want to add this key to the app config:

```
<add key="StationId" value="default" />
```

EDIT: Okay. So I figured out that I need to use XmlFile to append the attribute to the xml file. So I guess with this edit, how would I crate a text input in the installer that would save to the Value=[addStationId]